# Why is the risk set convex, when we allow for randomized estimators

Tags: bayesian, decision-theory, risk

A randomized estimator $\delta^*(X)$ such that its loss function $L(\theta,\delta^*(x))=\int_\mathcal{D}L(\theta,a)\delta^*(x,a) \ da$, where $\delta^*(x, \cdot)$ is the estimator's density on the decision set $\mathcal{D}$.

How can we prove that any randomized estimator's risk is a convex combination of the non-randomized estimators' risk?

I thought of something along these lines:

$R(\theta,\delta^*)=\int_\mathcal{X} \int_\mathcal{D}L(\theta,a)\delta^*(x,a) \ da \ f(x|\theta)\ dx = \int_\mathcal{D} R(\theta,a)\delta^*(x,a) \ da$

But I cannot use Fubini for the second equality since $\delta^*(x,a)$ depends on $x$. So, is there a way to rewrite this $\delta^*(x,a)$ into $f_x(x)\cdot f_a(a)$.

I tend to see $\delta^*(x,a)$ as $f(a|x)=f(x,a)/f(x)$, but it would be nice if it were $f(x,a)=f(x|a)f(a)$ instead...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The very formula for any randomized estimator is explicitly a convex combination of non-randomized estimators, so there's nothing to prove.

Comment: @whuber I'm not sure I follow you... Could you please elaborate more, in simple terms?

Comment: I'm not sure it could be any simpler: by definition, a randomized decision is a random selection among non-randomized decisions.  Because probabilities are non-negative, that's a convex combination.

Comment: @whuber but that's not the definition I use above. How would one deduce your sentence from the definition above?

Comment: @whuber Also, I'm interested in proving that the risk function of a randomized is a convex function, not the estimator

I've edited the question to reflect that. sorry